# Connect Frontend to Deployed Contract on Ropsten Testnet

Tags: web3js

I recently deployed a contract on the Ropsten testnet and am trying to connect my frontend to my deployed contract. I have created a contract instance with my ABI and contract address, however, my frontend is still not connecting properly. I am currently connecting to web3 via localhost 7545. Is this the problem? How can I resolve this? Help would be insanely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the problem.

Replace `http://localhost:7545` with `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YourInfuraProjectID`.